# Intellij will not open project files or create new project files

Tags: intellij-idea

I recently purchased a license for Intellij 12 but I cannot seem to make a go of it on OSX Mt. Lion. All files in the project have a red J icon and will not open by any means (clicking or drag and drop).

[image]

If I try to create a new file like a JavaScript file the dialog stays open and does not create the file.

I have:

- re-installed Intellij 3 times erasing all previous configurations
- Recreated/created new projects
- Created projects in alternate project folders
- Restarting my computer
- Checked file directory and file permissions

I cannot find a problem at all. RubyMine remains functional. Anyone else run into this problem and have an idea on how to correct it?

Comment: Do you have Markdown plugin installed? If yes, please try removing it (see http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-181)

Answer (score 3):

Certain plug-ins can break IntelliJ IDEA functionality. In this case the problem is caused by the **Markdown** plug-in that was compiled with JDK 1.7 and targeting JDK 1.7 language level. IDEA runs under JDK 1.6 on Mac, therefore plug-in breaks the IDE (you can find the exceptions in `idea.log`: `Help` | `Reveal Log in ...`).

To fix the problem manually delete the faulty plug-in from `~/Library/Application Support/IntelliJIdea12` directory. Users of other IntelliJ IDEA Platform based products or running under different OS can refer to [this document](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-181) to find the location of the plugins directory.